# Doing en efficient query using fulltextindex and other where conditions

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

My problem is the following :

I have a table mailmessage containing **23 millions lines** (1 year of data).
Here are the important fields of this table

- id (bigint)
- msgtimeutc (bigint)
- subject (tinytext)
- body (text)
- some other data to be displayed

I have a full text index on this table :
 `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX mailmessage_fulltext ON mailmessage (body,subject)`

I need to do a request **searching for text in body and subject AND narrowing by date time** on msgtimeutc like this :

```
SELECT M.some_data  
FROM mailmessage M 
WHERE M.MSGTIMEUTC >= 1343651965 AND M.MSGTIMEUTC <= 1344170365 
AND ( MATCH (M.BODY,M.SUBJECT) AGAINST ('test'));
```

mySQL

- can't use 2 indexes at the same time (the one on msgtimeutc and the fulltextindex). So my query ends doing a full table scan on msgtimeutc
- I can't include msgtimeutc in the fulltext index as it is a bigint and I am doing above or below on it

So the query is taking way too long time (and I/O) !

I tought about doing an *intersect* like this (sample code not tested)

```
SELECT M1.some_data FROM mailmessage M1 
WHERE M1.MSGTIMEUTC >= 1343651965 AND M1.MSGTIMEUTC <= 1344170365 
INTERSECT
SELECT M2.some_data FROM mailmessage M2 
WHERE ( MATCH (M2.BODY,M2.SUBJECT) AGAINST ('test'));
```

Explain (sorry for the scrollbar) :

```
+----+-------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+ 
| id | select_type | table | type     | possible_keys                   | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       | 
+----+-------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+ 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | M     | fulltext | msgtimeutc,mailmessage_fulltext | mailmessage_fulltext | 0       |      |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

but it doesn't exist on mySQL

Other requests like the 2 below are also doing full table scans

```
SELECT M.some_data 
FROM mailmessage M 
WHERE 
M.id in ( 
   select m2.id from mailmessage m2 use index(mailmessage_fulltext)
   where (MATCH (m2.BODY,m2.SUBJECT) AGAINST ('test')) 
) 
AND M.MSGTIMEUTC >= 1343651965 AND M.MSGTIMEUTC <= 1344170365;
```

or

```
SELECT M1.ATTACHMENTCOUNT AS ATCH_COUNT 
FROM mailmessage AS M1 
INNER JOIN mailmessage AS M2 ON M1.id = M2.id 
WHERE (M1.MSGTIMEUTC >= 1343651965 AND M1.MSGTIMEUTC <= 1344170365) 
AND (MATCH (M2.BODY,M2.SUBJECT) AGAINST ('test'))
```

both queries explain plans shows me only one index used (the fulltext)

So I may end up filtering programmaticaly lines by date ... but I would prefer (regarding the volume) a database solution

Any idea ?

Comment: Could you show the results of `EXPLAIN` for your first query?

Comment: explain result added for the first query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of latest MySQL version there is no way to combine full-text index with some another

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-merge-optimization.html

> Index Merge is not applicable to full-text indexes. We plan to extend it to cover these in a future MySQL release.

You may try to workaround your problem with temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_search 
  (FULLTEXT INDEX mailmessage_fulltext(body,subject))         
SELECT M.some_data  
FROM mailmessage M 
WHERE M.MSGTIMEUTC >= 1343651965 AND M.MSGTIMEUTC <= 1344170365
```

And then match it with query

```
SELECT M.some_data  
FROM my_search M 
WHERE ( MATCH (M.BODY,M.SUBJECT) AGAINST ('test'));
```

Keep in mind, that for this solution, full-text index in real table becomes totally useless.

Comment: Thanks that's brilliant  
I have two cases :   
If the searched word is not common : fulltext is fast and returns a few lines that are easy to be filtered by date (by mySQL or by Java)  
If the searched word is common then your solution works better to restrict by date first. 
  
I am working on a solution to guess in which case I am (I may have to block common words)